# Split to volumes using batch

Tags: batch-file, winrar, filesplitting

I am using the following command in a batch file in order to archive MY_LARGE_FOLDER and my .rar file is too big:

```
WinRAR a -r D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER.rar D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER\*.txt D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER\
```

1. How can I archive MY_LARGE_FOLDER, into small .rar files of 4MB each using batch file?
   (or in other words, How to use the "Split to volumes, bytes" option using batch file?)

Thanks.

Thanks for the help!
I used the -v switch:

```
          WinRAR a -r **-v4000** D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER.rar D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER\*.txt D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER\
```

and I got now 4 files of 4000 bytes each but after opening some of the files I saw that the files are duplicated on more than one archive (e.g. on Part01.rar and on Part02.rar) ???
1. I also tried the -s (solid) switch and the result is the same?
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6):

There are two "manuals" installed with *WinRAR*:

1. The help file `WinRAR.chm` which has on tab **Contents** the item **Command line mode** with the subitem **Switches** with a link to page **Switch -V<n>[k|b|f|m|M|g|G] - create volumes**, and
2. the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* which is the manual for console version `Rar.exe`. It contains nearly the same information as the help file regarding the available switches and their explanation.

I suggest to use in a batch file the console version with the command line:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -idcdp -m5 -md4m -r -s -v4M "D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER.rar" "D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER\"
```

Console application `Rar.exe` compresses `D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER\` with all files and subfolders with folder name `MY_LARGE_FOLDER` included into an archive with nearly no output to console window using best compression creating a multivolumne solid archive with 4 MB dictionary size (in case of lots of small *.txt files) and 4 MB per archive file (volume).

There can be used alternatively:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 -md4m -r -s -v4M "D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER.rar" "D:\MY_LARGE_FOLDER"
```

That creates nearly same archive with the difference that folder name `MY_LARGE_FOLDER` is not included in the archive (backslash at end removed) and no message written to console window (`-inul` instead of `-idcdp`).

Answer (score 0):

My solution for 20Mb volumes was:

`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinRAR.Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -idcdp -m5 -md4096 -r -s -v20M "C:\test.rar" "C:\test\"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `-v` flag to set the volume size. And based on that WinRAR will create volumes. Let us see an example:

```
winrar.exe a -v100m output.rar "{path_to_large_folder_or_file}"
```

This command will create volumes of size 100mb. You can use any integer with:
**[b | k | m | g]** -> bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes.